# Import Java classes into Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, import

I have a folder with a few Java files (translated into Java by CS2J) that I want to use to my Android project. How can I import them to my project without adding those classes manually to my project?

Comment: by adding them to java source folder?

Comment: have you tried copying and pasting those classes in your android project package?

Answer (score 0):

Just copy all of those Java files and paste them in the desired `package` in android under `src` folder. If those Java files do not have compile time error then you program will run.

In case you have to access them, just make the object and put your cursor to the ClassName then hit `Alt + Enter`. Paste those classes inside package inside the Java folder directly from Android Studio.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help.I've already paste them under src folder, but i fail to use them.They also appear with the red J Letter.

Comment: Bro at first delete this question . This might get you banned from posting in stackoverflow .. then  we can talk in comment

Comment: I know this is a really NOOB question, but still i can't find a solution.I've moved the folder under src folder, project compiles but still i can't import any of the classes.As if they didn't exist.

Comment: move it to src java folder

Comment: Thanks again!But when i copy those classes (or the folder) under java/src/com.packagename they don't compile as their imports fail.If i open them though as a new android project imports work fine.

Comment: delete all the imports and re import them it may help